# How to compute occurence probability of rows inside a SQL (MySQL) table using a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, probability

I have a table containing some similar rows representing objects for a game. I use this table as a way to select objects randomly. Of course, I ignore the size of the table. My problem is that I would like to have a single query that returns the probability to select every object and I don't know how to proceed.

I can get the total number of objects I have in my table:

```sql
select count(id) from objects_desert_tb;
```

Which returns

```sh
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|        81 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and I have a query that return the number of occurence of every object in the table:

```sql
select name, (count(name)) from objects_desert_tb group by name;
```

which gives:

```sh
+-------------------+---------------+
| name              | (count(name)) |
+-------------------+---------------+
| carrots           |             5 |
| metal_scraps      |            14 |
| plastic_tarpaulin |             8 |
| rocks_and_stones  |            30 |
| wood_scraps       |            24 |
+-------------------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Computing the probability for every object just consist in doing (count(name)) divided by the total number of rows in the table. For example with the row carrots, just compute 5/81, from the two queries given above. I would like a single query that would return:

```sh
+-------------------+---------------+
| carrots           |             5/81 = 0.06172839
| metal_scraps      |            0.1728...
| plastic_tarpaulin |            0.09876...
| rocks_and_stones  |            0.37...
| wood_scraps       |            0.29...
+-------------------+---------------+
```

Is there a way to use the size of the table as a variable inside a SQL query? Maybe by nesting several queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross join your queries:

```
select c.name, c.counter / t.total probability
from (
  select name, count(name) counter 
  from objects_desert_tb 
  group by name
) c cross join (
  select count(id) total 
  from objects_desert_tb 
) t
```

Comment: Ok, you are very quick at updating your answer ;). This is very good. I get: ```sh +-------------------+-------------+
| name              | probability |
+-------------------+-------------+
| carrots           |      0.0617 |
| metal_scraps      |      0.1728 |
| plastic_tarpaulin |      0.0988 |
| rocks_and_stones  |      0.3704 |
| wood_scraps       |      0.2963 |
+-------------------+-------------+ ```

Comment: Just, is there a way to get more that 4 digits in the returned probability ?

Comment: Try: `1.00000 * c.counter / t.total`

Comment: Ok, so nice, it works perfectly well. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you would just use window functions:

```
select name, count(*) as cnt,
       count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from objects_desert_tb 
group by name;
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. I get this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() as ratio
from objects_desert_tb 
group by name' at line 2
Any idea of the problem ?

Comment: @Onyr . . . You are probably using an older version of MySQL.

Comment: ok I will check that, thak you. Any quick command to do it on linux ubuntu ?

Comment: @Onyr . . . You can run `select version()`.